# applicationDidBecomeActive not being called at all

Tags: ios, state

I am using an `NSLog` statement in order to understand when `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` gets called, but it seems that it never gets called. Here is the code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
      NSLog(@"Some message");
}
```

The `-viewDidLoad` method seems to execute the very first time the application starts, but `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` never gets called. I click on the home button and reactivate the application several times, but still no message from `-applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you put this code in the Application Delegate file?

Comment: Obviously not, I had it in the ViewController.m. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: perfect, thanks alot! I made the same misstake by putting it into the ViewController!